# Woocommerce - remove product from category

Tags: php, categories, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, production

I'm trying to do the following, but I'm stuck with coding.
Hope someone can help me out here.

In Woocommerce (on the product-edit page) I can choose in which category the product will be.
I made a code where the product will be put in an extra category 'Aanbiedingen' (id=87) upon save, when there are certain conditions.

```
if ( !empty ($_POST['sale_enddate']) && ($_POST['sale_begindate']) ) {
    $cat_ids = array( 87 );
    wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, $cat_ids, 'product_cat', true );
    }
```

Now I would like to have a code where (upon save) the product will be removed from the 'Aanbiedingen' category, but it will still be in other categories.

Example: The product is in category 'Aanbiedingen', 'Comfort', 'Therapie' and 'Warmtezakken'
Can someone help me with a code where (upon save) the product will only be in 'Comfort', 'Therapie' and 'Warmtezakken' ?

I guess it has something todo with getting categories with `wp_get_object_terms` , removing value 'Aanbiedingen' (or id 87) and saving this altered array back with `wp_set_object_terms`?

I tried several things, but I can't get it done.
Can someone please help me?

Comment: it is harder to help if you don't show the code that doesn't work

Comment: I was looking for (new) code that works, not repairing existing code. 
I just found my answer below...  wp_remove_object_terms()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wp_remove_object_terms( $product_id, 'Aanbiedingen', 'product_cat' );